# move left column below center column on resize

Tags: html, css

I have a basic 3 column layout and for mobile, I want the left sidebar to move below the center column. Here is the basic HTML structure:

```
<header></header> 
<div class="page-container">

<div class="left-column"></div>
<div class="center-column"></div>
<div class="right-column"></div>

</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Here is a picture showing what I want to accomplish:

[image]

It doesn't matter much to me whether the red box winds up on top of the blue box or vise versa.

Comment: There are really heaps of resources online to do this using media queries. I suggest to do a bit of googling: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for that.

```css
.page-container{
  background-color: black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-column{
  background-color: red;
  flex: 2;
}
.center-column{
  background-color: green;
  flex: 5;
}
.right-column{
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 2;
}

@media(max-width:640px){
  .page-container{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.left-column{
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
}
.center-column{
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.right-column{
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  order:3;
}
}
```

```html
<header></header> 
<div class="page-container">

<div class="left-column">left</div>
<div class="center-column">center</div>
<div class="right-column">right</div>

</div>
<footer></footer>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0):

Changing how a page looks based on screen size is done with a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). You're probably going to want to have several different media queries, but a standard would be:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .left-column, .center-column, .right-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

You could do this by specifying a bunch of media queries yourself, but I would recommend looking into a framework to handle the 'snap points' for you.

One I would strongly recommend for you is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can lay out both the desktop and mobile views in flexbox, and use `order` to re-position the content divs with media queries.

Here's a quick example.

```css
body,html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header,footer {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
}

.page-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.left-column {
  background: red;
}
.center-column {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.right-column {
  background: blue;
}
.left-column,.right-column {
  width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .page-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .center-column {
    order: -1;
  }
  .left-column,.right-column {
    min-height: 25px;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="page-container">

  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="center-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column"></div>

</div>
<footer></footer>
```